# Generating Bitmap of WPF UIElement in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, wpf, uielement, rendertargetbitmap

I'm trying to generate a bitmap off a WPF border. The whole thing sits in a asp.net app (server side of course) running .net 4.0.

The problem is, that the generated image is, well, empty. Does anyone have an idea why?

Here's the code.

```
public static byte[] Draw(int width, int height)
    {
        MemoryStream memoryStream
            = new MemoryStream();
        Thread t = new Thread(delegate()
            {
                System.Windows.Controls.Border border = new System.Windows.Controls.Border()
                {
                    Background = Brushes.Red,
                    BorderBrush = Brushes.Green,
                    CornerRadius = new System.Windows.CornerRadius(5),
                    Width = width,
                    Height = height
                };

                border.ApplyTemplate();

                RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = 
                    new RenderTargetBitmap(width, height, 90, 90, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);

                renderTargetBitmap.Render(border);

                BitmapEncoder bitmapEncoder = 
                    new PngBitmapEncoder();

                bitmapEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTargetBitmap));
                bitmapEncoder.Save(memoryStream);
            });
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
        bool success = t.Join(5000);

        if (success)
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        else
            throw new Exception("Fail");
    }
```

The result is quite bad, as I said the thing returns the image with the right width and height, but it's empty, so I guess I don't mess the thing up with the threading bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add right after `border.ApplyTemplate`:

```
border.Measure(new Size(width, height));
border.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
border.UpdateLayout();
```

Your border didn't update itself before you are saving it.